# Java Regex Pattern doesn't do what the online testing tools say

Tags: java, regex, expression

I have a problem with a regular expression in Java. The following should be matched

```
2x 1 piece
63x 9 pieces
4x 1 piece
1 piece
23 pieces
```

with this regex:

```
((\w+)x\s)*(\w+)\s*(\w*)
```

As we all know, we have to escape strings in Java. I escaped the regex and I tried to use this one:

```
String regex = "((\\w+)x\\s)*(\\w+)\\s*(\\w*)";
```

Now comes my problem: All online services for regular expressions mark my pattern as valid, except the ones for java. They don't mark what could be false so I can't really see my problem. This is the code I'm trying to use in Java:

```
String regex = "((\\w+)x\\s)*(\\w+)\\s*(\\w*)";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = r.matcher(someClassWithMethods.text());
int multiplier=0;
int value= 0;
String supplement = "";
if (m.find( )) {
    multiplier= Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
    value= Integer.parseInt(m.group(3));    
    supplement = m.group(4);
}
```

I debugged the whole thing to see what's going on and all variables are as expected but I still get an empty group. What's wrong with this regex?

**EDIT**

I've changed some few things due to the comments and I've catched my NumberException with an additional if clause. Now I still don't get a matching result. What could that be?
There's my new code:

```
String regex = "(?:(\\w+)x\\s)?(\\d+\\s+)(pieces?)";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = r.matcher(quantityCell.text());
int quantityMultiplier = 0;
int quantity = 0;
String supplement = "";
if (m.find( )) {
    if(m.group(1) != null){ 
            quantityMultiplier = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
    }
    quantity = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));    
    supplement = m.group(3);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "empty group"? What is the exact output you are getting? I tried it and it's working fine for me...

Comment: Your regex is really ineffcient . Why not use `(?:\\w+x\\s)?\\d+\\s+pieces?` (untested code)

Comment: I guess NumberFormatException? But with your code (if instead of while), I don't think it will get this exception.

Comment: I mean that the matcher group values are not as I expect them to be. If I debug my program, I receive a group with the following values: [0, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]. The place 1 in the group array is fine because it's the matched 1 from "1 piece". But where is the word "piece" stored? It seems as if it wouldn't match it correctly.

Comment: @TheRealNoXx: I'm not sure what you want to do here. I can explain the code in the Pattern class if you point out the method name, but you didn't mention the method name. If you want to make your code work, you don't need to debug it into the Pattern class. Show us the test case where your actual value is not your expected value.

Comment: Please add the information to the question rather than in a comment. Many people don't notice the comment and what you added about the group is an important part of the question.

Comment: @nhahtdh I just want to get "1" and "piece" in separate groups. I've got a price list and I want to calculate the prices per unit. The reason why I have to use a regex is, that I don't know which format I'm getting from the database. As you can see from above, I get it one time with an x, the other one with "pieces" instead of piece etc. My values aren't consistent, that's the real problem. In my test case I'm getting "1 piece" from the database and it gives me these group values: [0, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]

Comment: I think there is something else (no-break-space, for example) between "1" and "piece" which causes the 4th capturing group to fail to match and capture empty string instead. `\s` by default only match ASCII space characters.

Comment: @nhahtdh and how can I check for no-break-space characters?

Comment: The thing is that `multiplier= Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));` may cause an issue since the 2nd group is [not initialized in every case](https://ideone.com/Oq1y1g). If you add a check if the group is not null, you will get [no errors](https://ideone.com/NZOAGK).

Comment: @stribizhev oh my gosh... I haven't thought about that. Thanks, that was really dumb <.<. 
Shame on me...
Have a nice day and thanks for the help nhahtdh & stribizhev :)

Comment: @TheRealNoXx: `"((\\w+)x(?U:\\s))*(\\w+)(?U:\\s*)(\\w*)"` This makes `\s` follows Unicode standard definition of whitespace character.

Comment: @TheRealNoXx: Does it mean that is the answer? Shall I post it?

Comment: @stribizhev It fixes my exception but I still don't get the right values. I'll update my post with my new modifications.

Comment: Now, you capture a space with the 2nd group. You need to [move it out of the capturing group](https://regex101.com/r/oG3cG6/1). Anyway, you got an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regular expression is weird:

- `\w+` Why match "word character" when you are only interested in digits in the first two instances?
- `((\w+)x\s)` Why is this a capturing group? You don't want result.
- `((\w+)x\s)*` Why is this repeating? Are you expecting multiple multipliers? Regular expression would only capture last multiplier if more than one was present.

Let's try with this instead:

```
(?:(\d+)x\s)?(\d+)\s(\w*)
```

Since the first capture is optional, it will be `null` if not present, so you need to check for that.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test("2x 1 piece");
    test("63x 9 pieces");
    test("4x 1 piece");
    test("1 piece");
    test("23 pieces");
}
private static void test(String input) {
    String regex = "(?:(\\d+)x\\s)?(\\d+)\\s(\\w*)";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    if (m.find()) {
        int multiplier = (m.group(1) != null ? Integer.parseInt(m.group(1)) : -1);
        int value = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
        String supplement = m.group(3);
        System.out.printf("%d, %d, '%s'%n", multiplier, value, supplement);
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
2, 1, 'piece'
63, 9, 'pieces'
4, 1, 'piece'
-1, 1, 'piece'
-1, 23, 'pieces'
```